# Can DllMain be replaced in a C++/CX Windows Runtime Component?

Tags: c++, dll, windows-runtime, c++-cx, etw

I'm using WPP tracing and need to call the housekeeping macros `WPP_INIT_TRACING` and `WPP_CLEANUP` at appropriate times.
The recommendation for a normal C++ DLL is to do this in the `DllMain` on process attach/detach.

Since C++/CX hides the `DllMain` inside `vccorlib`, is there a "safe" way I could override that DllMain with my own, and pass on calls to the vccorlib one after I have done my WPP calls?

Comment: Hmm, no, vccorlib has the normal entrypoint, __DllMainCRTStartup@12.  Adding your own DllMain is not a problem.  Have you actually tried this?  Then show us and tells us what goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I tricked myself into believing this was not possible while reading MSDN. You are correct, adding a DllMain works fine.

Comment: An example would be awesome here. I'm getting linker errors when providing my own definition.

Comment: Nvm, just had to rebuild. This signature seems to do it: `BOOL WINAPI DllMain(_In_ HINSTANCE inst, _In_ DWORD reason, _In_opt_ void* pvreserved)`